# PHP Google maps - location red balloon not shown

Tags: javascript, php, api, google-maps

I have the following code to display my home. But in my Webpage, it shows only my city generally. It does not show my location specifically although I used correct altitude and longitude from the URL shown;

I want like this;

[I want image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlCIB.jpg)

But now it shows like this;

[now image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPdcw.jpg)

Here is my code;

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
    </script>

    <script>
        function initialize(){
            var mapProp = {
                center:new google.maps.LatLng(6.2422975,80.0603382),//latitude and longitude respectively
                zoom:13,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:680px;height:400px;"> </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining the map, but you're not defining the marker for the map.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers